# How to use public toilets correctly?

Tags: salat, wudu

Salam

I’m usually out during the day and have to use public toilets when I need to go.
Most of the time however the toilets are dirty and I feel unclean after using them. Sometimes have to stand up which I know is wrong but the toilets are dirty people do their business all over the seat sometimes.
What to do in this case? I know this will affect my salah it probably isn’t even valid but what’s the alternative if I have to rely on public toilets during the day ?
Of course I can use the mosque toilets when I’m there but I mean in general when you’re out and have to rely on public toilets. I can’t shower before each salah because I’m out and I can’t take a change of clothes with me every time
Please help

Comment: The toilets at mosques are also public. What exactly is your fear and why?

Comment: I think the person is referring to restroom open to anyone like in a shopping centre or a restaurant

Comment: If you insist on using public toilets, is there anything more you can do than being extra careful?. Feeling unclean and actually having najis on you is very different.

Comment: @Usman maybe you haven't seen toilets of mosques that are as disgusting as public toilets in which none is doing cleaning or maybe one cleaning once in a while.

Comment: @Medi1Said I haven’t come across any mosque toilets that are as bad as public ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the restroom in a public place then you can wipe the seats with the toilet paper provided and then place a layer or 2 on the seat itself so you aren’t in direct contact with the toilet seat. And just carry an empty water bottle with you so you can make istinja, just fill the bottle with water before going into the cubicle.